# Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php, When call a function from another controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**contrller:News.php**
This is my controller News

```
<?php class News extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
}
public function getShowIN_News()
{
    return $result;
} } ?>
```

**contrller:Category.php**
This is my controller Category

```
<?php class Category extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
}
public function category()
{
    require('news.php');
    $test = new News();
    $data["headlines"] = $test->getShowIN_News();
} }?>
```

Comment: where are you using session in above controller?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html and  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score 1):

By using an empty constructor, you're making it so that `CI_Controller::__construct()` isn't called, and that's where everything in the framework is initialized.

I know you've put it there to *hack* it so you can call one controller from another, but it is very intentionally made that way, exactly so you don't do this.

Comment: Then, how can i do this. i want call getShowIN_News() in category controller.

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. If you need to reuse that code, it doesn't belong in a controller ... put it in a model.